Добавить параметр в url
Изначальный адрес страницы может быть любым, с гет параметрами, без них.
С ключем вроде: site.ru#dds или такой site.ru/?sdf=ddd или site.ru
Необходимо добавить в url, get параметр. Вопрос в том, возможно есть готовая функция в php.
Чтобы не мучаться с проверками на присутствие ? или #. То есть чтобы просто к текущему url добавить параметр без головной боли...

нет. готовых функций чтоб прям встроить нет. но есть функции для парсинга и построения, типа parse_url, parse_str, http_build_query, с помощью которых можно сделать нужную для себя функцию
